# LibGDX touchDown only works on Android, not on Desktop

Tags: java, android, libgdx

During development in Android Studio, I have faced a problem in connection with touching and clicking on an actor.

I am working with the help of this tutorial:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx

And the code snippet is this:

```
public class MyActor extends Actor {
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/jet.png"));
    float actorX = 0, actorY = 0;
    public boolean started = false;

    public MyActor(){
        setBounds(actorX,actorY,texture.getWidth(),texture.getHeight());
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ((MyActor)event.getTarget()).started = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        batch.draw(texture,actorX,actorY);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        if(started){
            actorX+=5;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am debugging on both Android and PC. With this snippet, if I click on the actor either on PC or on my phone, the actor moves just fine.

However, I have made a few modifications to this code to fit my needs, this is how it looks like now:

```
public class Play_Btn extends Actor {

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menubuttons/play_btn.png"));

    float actorX = game.screen_width/2 - tiledimensions*4/2;
    float actorY = tiledimensions*howmanytobottom-tiledimensions*5;

    public boolean started = false;

    public Play_Btn(){
        setBounds(actorX,actorY,tiledimensions*4,tiledimensions*4);
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ((Play_Btn)event.getTarget()).started = true;
                Gdx.app.debug("The button has been pressed", "");
                return true;
            }

        });
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){

        batch.draw(texture, actorX,actorY, tiledimensions*4, tiledimensions*4);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){


        if(started){
            actorX +=5 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the situation is that if I debug this on Android, it works the same way, no problems at all.

However, if I click on this actor on PC, nothing happens, and I am curious why this is the case.

Has anyone have ever encountered this issue or something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the value of tiledimensions, how you calculate this ?

Comment: Did you remember to set your Stage as the app's input listener? `Gdx.input.setInputListener(stage)`

Comment: Yes,  I set the inputlistener. Tiledimensions is equal to (screenwidth/10)

Comment: Did you update the Stage's Viewport in resize?